# Mysql - Update row if value is not present in other rows of same table

Tags: mysql

I need to write single query which will update rows and skip row if that value is already present in same table.
i.e. I want to update team to game only if that team is not playing in game of same event(eventID).

Here is the query

```
update tbl_games m INNER JOIN bcs_event e on e.id = m.eventID SET m.team_id=1;
```

I tried following two solutions in where statements

```
WHERE(NOT EXISTS(select m1.id from tbl_games  as m1 where m1.eventID=e.id and m1.team_id=1 ))
```

> This saying "You can't specify target table 'm' for update in FROM clause"

```
WHERE (NOT EXISTS(select * from (select m1.id from tbl_games as m1 where m1.eventID=e.id and m1.team_id=1) as tmp))
```

> This is saying "Unknown column 'e.id' in 'where clause'"

**Here's the sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE bcs_event (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE tbl_games (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_id` INT NULL,
  `team_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `evid_idx` (`event_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `evid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`)
    REFERENCES bcs_event (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

INSERT INTO bcs_event (`Name`) VALUES ('Softball Event');
INSERT INTO bcs_event (`Name`) VALUES ('Baseball Event');
INSERT INTO bcs_event (`Name`) VALUES ('Soccer Event');

INSERT INTO tbl_games (`event_id`, `team_id`) VALUES ('1', '11');
INSERT INTO tbl_games (`event_id`, `team_id`) VALUES ('1', '22');
INSERT INTO tbl_games (`event_id`) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO tbl_games (`event_id`) VALUES ('1'); 

update tbl_games m INNER JOIN bcs_event e on e.id = m.event_id SET m.team_id=11
where m.team_id is NULL and (NOT EXISTS(select g.id from tbl_games as g where g.eventID=e.id and g.team_id=11));
```

Comment: can you please provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: @Simonare I have added sample data in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE bcs_event (
>   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tbl_games (
>   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `event_id` INT NULL,
>   `team_id` INT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   INDEX `evid_idx` (`event_id` ASC),
>   CONSTRAINT `evid`
>     FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`)
>     REFERENCES bcs_event (`id`)
>     ON DELETE NO ACTION
>     ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO bcs_event (`Name`) VALUES ('Softball Event');
> INSERT INTO bcs_event (`Name`) VALUES ('Baseball Event');
> INSERT INTO bcs_event (`Name`) VALUES ('Soccer Event');
> INSERT INTO tbl_games (`event_id`, `team_id`) VALUES ('1', '11');
> INSERT INTO tbl_games (`event_id`, `team_id`) VALUES ('1', '22');
> INSERT INTO tbl_games (`event_id`) VALUES ('1');
> INSERT INTO tbl_games (`event_id`) VALUES ('1');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> update tbl_games m 
> INNER JOIN bcs_event e 
>   on e.id = m.event_id 
> SET m.team_id=11
> where m.team_id is NULL and 
> NOT EXISTS ( 
>   select l.id 
>   from (select g.id from tbl_games as g 
>   where g.event_id=(SELECT e.id 
>                          FROM   bcs_event e 
>                          WHERE e.id = g.event_id) and g.team_id=11) l
>   );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0bc00d2b578a28067e5eb73ba7be668)*

Comment: Actually I need bcs_event in JOIN with tbl_games, to access few more information from events table. thats why cant remove event table from JOIN

Comment: Yes that also I had tried before.
This is saying "Unknown column 'e.id' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Please check main post.. I have added sample data